# How to calculate number of true members in state and update to the screen?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I'm recently working with react.js and want to create a todo-app.
In my state, I write the following:

```
this.state={tasks: [ ["Eat",true],
["Sleep",false],
["Read",true]]}
```

This state will be rendered into different checkboxs.

And in the content I want to render:

```
<div className="todo-app__total">{Num} Left</div>
```

The `Num` here is the variable I want to demonstrate how many items are there that are still not completed (false). In the above case, `Num`=2.

The other buttons are functioning properly now, so the state may dynamically change through time, but I hope that `Num` can change simultaneously when the state has been updated.

How do I collect the number of true members, while they are not in the same array (In same column)?

Comment: simple use loop/logic and save this variable in state or calculate on each render (not preferred)

Comment: How about `this.state.tasks.filter(task=>task[1]).length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an object like,

{name: 'Sleep', completed: false}

you can check as follows,

```
items.filter(item=>item.completed == true)?.length
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for an easy solution, just use the following

```
  <button>{this.state.tasks.filter(task=>task[1] == true)?.length}</button>
```

But I am not sure whether that will work, you should create another state, not necessarily, but it's clean and easy to understand. Also, you should have an array of objects.

```
this.state={
  tasks: [ 
      {name: "Eat", completed: true},
      {name: "Sleep", completed: false},
      {name: "Read", completed: true}
    ],
    done: 2,
  }
```

This is the right way to do it.
Then just read this from the button.

```
  <div className="todo-app__total">{done} Left</div>
```

And after you complete a todo, just increase or decrease the done value like the following.

```
  // After completing a todo
  this.setState({ done: done++ })

  // after undoing a todo
  this.setState({ done: done-- })
```

And if you need any more help, just show me the full code.

Comment: Thanks for reminding that i should use an array of object! Because I used to use c++ and use a lot of 2D array (haha)

Comment: Also, I want to ask, after I change to use an array of object, I want to add a button that can display only the items that satisfy completed:true. How do i implement it? (The full code is in my another question, I don't know how to post it here)

Comment: You can use a map function to loop through the tasks array and if completed == true, then show the button.
```
  {this.tasks.map(task => {
    if (task.completed) {
      return <button>{task.name}</button>
    }
  }}
```